# Writing list and list of list inside the same file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file say, `file1.txt` which looks something like below.

```
27,28,29,30,1,0.67
31,32,33,34,1,0.84
35,36,37,38,1,0.45
39,40,41,42,1,0.82
43,44,45,46,1,0.92
43,44,45,46,1,0.92
51,52,53,54,2,0.28
55,56,57,58,2,0.77
59,60,61,62,2,0.39
63,64,65,66,2,0.41
75,76,77,78,3,0.51
90,91,92,93,3,0.97
```

Where the last column is the fitness and the 2nd last column is the class.
Now I read this file like :

```
rule_file_name = 'file1.txt'
rule_fp = open(rule_file_name)

list1 = []
for line in rule_fp.readlines():
    list1.append(line.replace("\n","").split(","))
```

Then a default dictionary was created to ensure the rows are separated according to the classes.

```
from collections import defaultdict

classes = defaultdict(list)
for _list in list1:
    classes[_list[-2]].append(_list)
```

Then they are paired up within each class using the below logic.

```
from random import sample, seed
seed(1)
for key, _list in classes.items():
    _list=sorted(_list,key=itemgetter(-1),reverse=True)

    length = len(_list)
    middle_index = length // 2
    first_half = _list[:middle_index]
    second_half = _list[middle_index:]
    result=[]
    result=list(zip(first_half,second_half))
```

Later using the 2 rows of the pair, a 3rd row is being created using the below logic:

```
ans=[[random.choice(choices) for choices in zip(*item)] for item in result]
```

So if there were initially `12 rows` in the file1, that will now form 6 pairs and hence 6 new rows will be created. I simply want to append those newly created rows to the file1 using below logic:

```
list1.append(ans)
print(ans)
    
with open(f"output.txt", 'w') as out:
    new_rules = [list(map(str, i)) for i in list1]
    for item in new_rules:
        out.write("{}\n".format(",".join(item)))
        #out.write("{}\n".format(item))
```

But now my `output.txt` looks like:

```
27,28,29,30,1,0.67
31,32,33,34,1,0.84
35,36,37,38,1,0.45
39,40,41,42,1,0.82
43,44,45,46,1,0.92
43,44,45,46,1,0.92
51,52,53,54,2,0.28
55,56,57,58,2,0.77
59,60,61,62,2,0.39
63,64,65,66,2,0.41
75,76,77,78,3,0.51
90,91,92,93,3,0.97
['43', '44', '41', '46', '1', '0.82'],['27', '28', '45', '46', '1', '0.92'],['35', '36', '33', '38', '1', '0.84']
['55', '60', '57', '58', '2', '0.77'],['51', '64', '53', '66', '2', '0.28']
['75', '91', '77', '93', '3', '0.51']
```

But my desired outcome is:

```
27,28,29,30,1,0.67
31,32,33,34,1,0.84
35,36,37,38,1,0.45
39,40,41,42,1,0.82
43,44,45,46,1,0.92
43,44,45,46,1,0.92
51,52,53,54,2,0.28
55,56,57,58,2,0.77
59,60,61,62,2,0.39
63,64,65,66,2,0.41
75,76,77,78,3,0.51
90,91,92,93,3,0.97
43,44,41,46,1,0.82
27,28,45,46,1,0.92
35,36,33,38,1,0.84
55,60,57,58,2,0.77
51,64,53,66,2,0.28
75,91,77,93,3,0.51
```

Comment: That isn't a text file, its a csv file and you'd find it much easier to import it as a csv file

Comment: Can you guide me in case of the above code, if I change the extension to `.csv` then how the code will be modified! Or what are the added benefits I am going to get!

Comment: You don't need to change the extension, even if you've called it a text file its still a csv file in its contents, [field names](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) for a start so you can read each line in as a dictionary with actual keys rather than hard to explain logic

Comment: Okay I got the logic, and understood. But for now just for the above case can you give me a solution please, else I need to change at different places and just for this case I want to keep this convention fixed.

Comment: Maybe you should do not list1.append(ans), but list1.extend(ans)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use numpy, it is flexible and compact.

```
import numpy as np

fin = 'file1.txt'
col1, col2, col3, col4, jclass, fitness = np.loadtxt(fin, unpack=True, delimiter=',')
rows = np.column_stack((col1, col2, col3, col4, jclass, fitness))

print(rows[0])
print(rows[-1])
print(fitness)
```

Then apply your logic to the `rows` array

Comment: Can you just give me the solution for the above case which is stated in the question! From the next time onward I will follow this approach.